# JQuery fadeout fading out too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a paragraph tag to fade out over 10 seconds, however it is fading out much faster than the intended 10 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<p>
    If you click on this paragraph you'll see it just fade away.
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("p").click(function () {
        $("p").fadeOut("10000");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How about `$("p").fadeOut(10000);`

Comment: You should have posted that as an answer Mike; comments can't be accepted as answers, even though you are right too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Drop the quotes to make it work with milliseconds, otherwise it will just use the default value, as "10000" is a string and not a time value, and it's not an accepted string like "slow" or "fast".

```
$("p").click(function () {
    $("p").fadeOut(10000);
});
```

Also, I like to reference things within scope like `this` :

```
$("p").on('click', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(10000);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8rmYB/)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the quotes around the fadeout time.   only quote around fadeout if you are using things like slow fast

```
$("p").click(function () {
    $("p").fadeOut(10000);
});
```

vs

```
$("p").click(function () {
    $("p").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

[Fiddle with both examples](http://jsfiddle.net/VTwU9/1/)